# Laravel fails to deserialize model with mysql's POINT column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a model where column `location` represents coordinates.
This column can be null. When it is null everything is fine, but when there is some data, then:

1. If it is used inside internal laravel events (which does not implement ShouldBroadcast) then I have to add `use SerializesModels`, otherwise field is not deserialized, exception is thrown

   `invalidPayloadException in Queue.php line 89`
2. If it ised inside `broadcast` laravel events (which must be delivered into browser) then node.js fails to parse it.

Example: `location` is null

Event:

```
{"event":"App\\Events\\ViewingUsersUpdated","data":{"users":[{"id":1,"created_at":"2017-04-12 07:20:16","updated_at":"2017-04-12 07:20:16","creator_id":null,"phone":"70000000000","first_name":"\u0410\u0434\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0440 1","last_name":"","middle_name":"","active":1,"manager_id":null,"avatar":"\/img\/profile.png","full_name":"70000000000 \u0410\u0434\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0440\u0430\u0442\u043e\u0440 1  ","user_timezone":"Europe\/Moscow"}],"instance":{"id":1,"created_at":"2017-04-12 11:29:06","updated_at":"2017-04-12 13:55:32","creator_id":1,"test_field_text":"1234567892131","user_field_single":null,"image_single":null,"location":null,"address_area":"b8837188-39ee-4ff9-bc91-fcc9ed451bb3","address_region":null,"address_city":"f66a00e6-179e-4de9-8ecb-78b0277c9f10","address_locality":null,"address_street":null,"modelType":"testing"}},"socket":null}
```

`location` is not null

Event:

```
undefined:1
```

P.S.

Mutator:

```
$this->attributes[$key] = DB::raw('POINT(' . $value . ')');
```

Accessor:

```
$value = unpack('Lpadding/corder/Lgtype/dlatitude/dlongitude', $value);
$value = $value['latitude'] . ',' .    $value['longitude'];
```

Comment: The line above the exception thrown is 
 if (JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error()) 


maybe you should stop there with xdebug and see with error is json_last_error retourning

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: I know the reason of the problem: laravel can not json_encode binary field returned from database, but how to fix it?

Comment: and if you do a base64_encode prior to the json_encode?

Comment: Ok, it works fine with base64_encode and backward with base64_decode, but how to force laravel to do it?

Comment: I don't know how is your code, but you should use the base64_encode function before calling to the queued job

Comment: It's not a job, it's just an event. I use it like `event(new MyEvent)`