# Overwrite serialization of eloquent model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, serialization

I have binary field in Eloquent model which is not properly serialized when used inside websocket events, so node.js fails to process it, because json_encode does not handle it well.

Can i overwrite how one property in my model serialized in restored?

Related question: [Laravel fails to deserialize model with mysql's POINT column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371890/laravel-fails-to-deserialize-model-with-mysqls-point-column)

Comment: You mean the JSON serialization, not the `serialize` serialization I'm assuming?

Comment: Yes, because it fails during json serialization (`POINT` column from mysql database can not be serialized to json).